# Saving core file in gdb

Tags: gdb, core-file

Is it possible to **save/dump** core file using gdb? Sometimes I want to save file to analyze it later.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

Issue the 'generate-core-file' command in gdb.

```
(gdb) help generate-core-file
Save a core file with the current state of the debugged process.
Argument is optional filename.  Default filename is 'core.<process_id>'.
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400e0b: file utils/udec.c, line 36.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/nos/build/utils/udec

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe9a8) at utils/udec.c:36
36              int fileargc = 1;
(gdb) generate-core-file
Saved corefile core.7336
```

Comment: It will be saved in GDB's current working directory, which can be seen via the `pwd` command.  If you need to change it, you can do so with `cd`, just like at a shell.

Comment: @Jonathon_Reinhart pass core-file path as `generate-core-file` first argument if you want to save it in certain place

Answer (score 27):

You can also use `gcore <pid>` to produce cores.

Comment: this should be in comment part

Comment: Please have  a look to this page http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment : When shouldn't I comment?...."Answering a question or providing an alternate solution to an existing answer;"

Comment: Looks like `gcore` is only supported in newer gdb versions. Old ones require `generate-core-file`.

Comment: This appears to be a short name for `generate-core-file`, both doing the same thing.